# How to import module without class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have 4 files in my project:

```
project/__init__.py
project/app.py
project/mod_x.py
project/mod_y.py
```

In mod_x.py I have a class (e.g. ModX)
In mod_y.py I have just one function.

I import modules from app.py as follows:

```
from .mod_x import ModX
import .mod_y
```

I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'mod_y'

Before I created **init**.py I didn't have that kind of problems (of course, I dont put "." before module name).

How to import module which doesn't have the class inside in Python3 with **init**.py file inside the current directory?

Comment: Location-wise, there is no difference between `mod_x` and `mod_y` (the contents of each module are irrelevant). Why wouldn't you import them both the same way (both with or both without the `.` that signifies a relative import)?

Comment: @chepner I made a mistake I import both with '.' I just edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relative imports are only available for `from...import` syntax.

You could import that function this way:

```
from .mod_y import FUNCTION_NAME
```

Module could be imported this way:

```
from . import mod_y
```

Comment: Is it root or `project` dir in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: sweet god, I spent a full day looking for this answer. Is there a reason why you can't just "import mod_y"?